# jQuery function (Window resized)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {

    resized();
    jQuery(window).resize(resized);

    function resized() {
        wd = parseInt(jQuery(window).width());
        if (wd >= 992) {
            var wrhei = jQuery(document).height();
            jQuery('#menu').height(wrhei);
        }
    }
});
```

I want to call function when I resize the page without refreshing the page just when I resize function happen

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @micnic so how comes that you approved clearly harmful question's edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    wd = parseInt(jQuery(window).width());
    if (wd >= 992) {
        var wrhei = jQuery(document).height();
        jQuery('#menu').height(wrhei);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code / approach, I am using in my project and it works great.
Call the $(window).resize function in the document ready event as shown below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        Resized();           
    });
});

function Resized()
{
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: @Regent: it was a typo. Removed it.